# ORDERS not showing as an Entity in Export function

Tags: export, importexport

Per this article, I should be able to export Order details...
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-to-export-orders

However, when I go to the Export function ORDERS is not in the list of selections to export.  The only selections I get to choose from in the Export function is PRODUCTS or CUSTOMERS.

Can you tell me how I can ORDERS as an export option?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible out of the box. Documentation you are looking at is for Magento Go which is shutting down in early 2015.